# I can't find the program "details"

Tags: menu

In the app-center, I see I have an app "details" (gnome-program). I can't see it in my menu and neither if I type it in the search field.

I had a similar problem with gnome contacts: I installed it, but could only open it from the terminal.

What can I do?